# Optimize algorithm to find intersection points in 2d roads (lines)

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, big-o

I have a list of Lines which represent Roads such that each road has a "StartingPoint" and an "EndingPoint". My goal is to find "Next" road of each road. **A road is Next of another road if its starting point OR ending point falls on top of the starting point or ending point of another road**. For example :

Road A :  starting point of : (0,0) and ending point of (2,0) 
Road B :  starting point of : (2,0) and ending point of (5,0) 
Road C:   starting point of : (2,0) and ending point of (4,2)

So Roads Next is will be :

A NEXT { B , C} 
B NEXT { A }
C NEXT { A }

My current algorthim is doing it in O(n^2) by comparing every starting point of a road to starting and ending of another road. How can make this faster. I think sorting the roads might work but I'm not sure. Please tell me what you think!

**Note:** Those who are saying use `Hashmap<Start/EndPoint,Road>` your solution is still O(N^2).

Comment: Could you "index" the roads in a multimap that uses the start/endpoint as a key, and all the roads with that point as values? From there, it should be pretty easy to build a directed graph.

Comment: Also I don't get what do you mean saying "each road has its beginning and its end". Why don't you make it possible to move in both directions?

Comment: @LysenkoAndrii because a road can be 2 way

Comment: @HiradRoshandel Is there a limit on the coordinates range? say (x,y) for x,y <= 10^9 ?

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you want to do with the result. The result of your calculation is of size `O(#roads^2)`. This means that if you want to iterate over it then you will need `O(#roads^2)` at best. This being said if you just want to be able to answer questions like "return all adjacencies of a given road" then you can do that in `O(#roads)` with the algorithm you implemented.

Comment: In my case it's not O(1) to find nexts I want to find nexts for all roads so it becomes O(n^2) again to go through all roads and all sets no?

Comment: Yeah, technically this is O(n) to find next for a single road because of the addAll call. So to find for all roads would be O(n^2) which is better than you O(n^3).

Comment: mine is O(n^2) too. im using nested for loops.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a `HashMap<XYPoint, HashSet<Road>> endPoints`, and another `HashMap<Road, HashSet<Road> next` should suffice; assuming your Road objects have a ending and starting `XYPoint` s. The logic would go as follows:

```
 for each road R,
     add it, using its starting point, to the endPoints map; and
             for each road X with a co-incident endpoint, 
                 next.put(R, X); next.put(X, R);                     
     add it, using its ending point, to the map endPoints map; and
             for each road X with a co-incident endpoint, 
                 next.put(R, X); next.put(X, R);
```

At the end of this procedure, your `next` map would contain the next roads for each road. You would just have to iterate this map to generate the desired output.

If there are no next roads, the algorithm is O(n). In the worst case (all roads have the same starting and ending points), it is O(n^2); you can eliminate this by using suitable equals/hashcode for your Roads, at the cost of some extra complexity (you would need to count repetitions).

Comment: isn't this same as Benjy Kessler above answer? Still O(n^2) no?

Comment: It is similar - I started to write before he posted, but finished afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest way to do this is to create a class Cell that would represent a certain point like (x;y). Override equals and hashCode of Cell and then simply store your Cell objects in a HashMap that guaranties a high speed of retrieving its elements.

Answer (score 0):

There's an O(n log n) algorithm, I'm not sure if there are any that are superior.

You can:

1) Create a Point class that consists of a 2D point, and a pointer to the road that it has an endpoint (starting point or ending point) of.

2) Create an Array twice as big as your collection of roads

3) Loop through all roads, and add a Point representing both the starting point or the ending point to an Array - have said Point point back to the road that created it.

4) Order the array using the sort of your choice.  You can use a lot of sorting functions, but since you're writing code I would say you use one that first sorts by y, then uses x to tiebreak on equal y's. So:

```
if ( a.y < b.y ) return -1;
if ( a.y > b.y ) return 1;
if ( a.x < b.x ) return -1;
if ( a.x > b.x ) return 1;
return 0;
```

Only for points you should probably rewrite it as non-branching if you care about speed.

5) Adjacent points may be the same.  Non-adjacent points are certainly not. Run through the ordered array in O(n) time.  Points refer back to their roads.  Combine as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

The storage of your final result doesn't have to be of size O(roads^2) if you allow 3 things:

- Store separate sub-lists for roads that overlap a road's start point and its end point. You can just concatenate the two lists together to get a road's complete next list when looking it up, or iterate through one and then the other.
- Share lists between roads. The start point list of one road might be another road's start or end point list. In other words, for each point there is a single list of all roads that either start or end there.
- Allow a road to be a member of its own lists (and just ignore it when retrieving the list).

The hash map you need is `HashMap<XYPoint, List<Road>>`

For each road, store `List<Road>` startList and endList

The algorithm is (pseudo-code):

```
For each road in list
    For point in [start, end]
        Look up List<Road> roadlist from hash map based on point X,Y
        If null then
            roadlist = new List<Road>
            add road to roadlist
            add roadlist to hash map
        else
            add road to roadList
        set roadList as either road.startList or road.endList
```

You only add each road to a List twice. Assuming hash lookups and adds are O(1) then this should be O(n).